# How to find the value in exact pattern and extract it into dataframe?

Tags: python, dataframe, python-re

I have some text files which were sent daily. They have same pattern (tag + value, end with quote notation) whose values changes in every files. You can see in images below:

[image]
[image]
[image]

My task is extract some tags (EQD+CN and RFF+BM) with their value and convert it into dataframe with the format like this:

```
    EQD_CN    RFF_BM
0   3+5     MEDUD6352618   
1   3+5     MEDUAE709954
2   ++4     null
```

Note: In the 3rd file image there is missing RFF+BM (this indicate the id) so it return null in the DataFrame.

Can anyone please help me to do this, I'm quite new in extract tasks in Python. Many thanks to you guys

Sample Data: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1mQUgbxql4qO1qtgdZkVgP3NysP9NtAVp?usp=sharing

Comment: If you have a specific issue while solving this yourself you can ask here with your code.

Comment: Hi @MichaelButscher, I have no idea to start so I really need some snippet code for help sir. I have searching solution all day long but I'm stuck so I really post question here to find someone help me

Comment: You should first work through the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) or another suitable tutorial if not done yet. There are pandas tutorials, too.

Comment: Dear @MichaelButscher , I have some knowledge about Python. I don't say that I start from scratch but this problem related to regular expression (I think so - I don't know best solution for this that why I ask for some help). Sorry for disturb your new feed and if you can help me then I'm very appreciate for your help. Have a good day

Comment: The relevant tags at the beginning both consist of first 6 characters. Therefore if `s` is a line of the file, you can check if `s[:6]` is equal to "EQD+CN" or "RFF+BM". In the first case you then have to extract `s[-4:-1]`, in the second `s[7:-1]`. These are string slices which are covered in the aforementioned tutorial.